# Working With Lists in HXT

Tags: haskell, hxt

I'm going crazy trying to use the simple `>>.` and `>.` functions defined [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/hxt/9.2.2/doc/html/Control-Arrow-ArrowList.html).

I want to get the length of **all** the text for a node in HXT. I'm using this:

```
runX (doc //> hasName "div" //> text >>. unlines)
```

Where `doc` is my `XmlTree` Arrow.

This gets me all the text for all divs (including text in any children they have). It gets the text as a string because I'm using `unlines`. Now I want to get the length of that string, so I try:

```
runX (doc //> hasName "div" //> text >>. unlines >. length)
```

And HXT seems to magically convert my string back into an array, because I get this:

```
[0,17,0,20,0,11,...]
```

What I want is all those `Int`s summed up. How would I do this?

**Update**:

The text function is defined like this:

```
text = deep (getChildren >>> getText)
```

I figured out that if I skip the `getChildren` bit, this works correctly:

```
text = deep getText
```

As long as I only have one `div` element. If I have multiple `div` elements, I get back an array with the length for each element.

Comment: I'm not familiar with HXT at all, but would just doing `... >>. length . unlines` work? Or maybe `... >>. (length . unlines)`, depending on operator precedence.

Comment: Nope. `>>.` expects a list as the result, so I would write your suggestion as: `runX (doc //> hasName "div" //> text >>. (\x -> [length . unlines $ x]))`. I get `[0,17,0,20,0,11,...]` as the result.

Comment: Why not just `sum $ runX ...`?

Comment: Because I want to write an arrow that does this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the next two examples:

```
Prelude Text.XML.HXT.Core> flip runLA undefined $ (constL [1, 2] >>>  arr id) >>. take 1
[1]
Prelude Text.XML.HXT.Core> flip runLA undefined $  constL [1, 2] >>> (arr id  >>. take 1)
[1,2]
```

The difference is only in brackets.
Without brackets it will work as the second example. So you have the issue cos different fixities.